# Unable to "cut" blocks of text from Microsoft Word sometimes

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word, cut-and-paste

Sometimes doing a cut operation does not have any effect both visually and at the clipboard level. The block of text just stays there. If there are multiple lines, it is usually one line that refuses to go away.

When I just select the other lines and do a cut, they do go away. After that, I have to erase the problematic line character by character then.

I'm using Microsoft Word on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Which version of Word do you have?

Comment: 2003 (11.8313.8221) SP3. Part of Office Professional.

Comment: More information if you are still having this problem? Do you only experience this problem in MS Word - does it also happen inside any other applications like notepad, your browser? Is it one specific block of text, or all over the document, and is it a certain document, some documents, or all documents?

Comment: This seemed to be an issue with MS Word only, not restricted to a block of text. It also happened to me for two different documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Office Diagnostics from the Help Menu.